# Extract text around the reference number in research document

Tags: java, regex, extract, text-mining

I want to extract the text surrounding the reference number.
for example:
text is :

> The sociological assumption is a constraint on the trust in the underlying social graph: the graph needs to have strong trust as evidenced,
>       for example, by face to face interaction demonstrating social nodes
>       knowledge of each other [10, 11]. While the first assumption has
>       been questioned recently in [8], where it is shown that even the honest subgraph may have some cuts that disrupt the algorithmic property on which Sybil defenses are based, the trust, though being a crucial requirement for these designs, was not considered carefully. Even worse, these defense [10, 11, 2, 4] — when verified against real-world networks — have considered samples of online social graphs, which are known to possess weaker value of  rust.

here i want to extract the cited text for reference number [8], and same for [10],[11] [2] and [4].

Comment: So for reference number `[8]`, it should return "While the first assumption has been questioned recently in" ?

Comment: it should return that sentence which have that reference number [8].

Comment: So my assumption is correct then? A simple yes/no (or even better providing examples) would be best

Comment: What is returned if there's multiple references in a sentence?

Comment: @Ascalonian yes, u are correct , it should return ' While the first assumption has been questioned recently in, where it is shown that even the honest subgraph may have some cuts that disrupt the algorithmic property on which Sybil defenses are based, the trust, though being a crucial requirement for these designs, was not considered carefully.'

Comment: Does all that get included because `[8]` is in the middle of the sentence and not directly before a period? I think you need to describe what exactly you need and also provide the code you have used already.

Comment: @Ascalonian actually i am new to regular expressions, so i didnt try it. reference number can be anywhere, it can be in middle , at start or at end of sentence. i want that whole sentence to be returned.

Comment: @Ascalonian can u plz show me the regex for the same??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually given an example of the output you wish to collect. Neither have you provided any code that you have used to attempt this.

Anyway. If I assume you want all of the text prior to the citation then your regular expression would be something like:

```
(.*?)\[(.*?)\]
```

This captures two groups, the first being the text and the second being the citation. You can apply this to the text with the following code:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\[(.*?)\\]");

public static void extract(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String text = matcher.group(1);
        String citation = matcher.group(2);

        System.out.println("The text: '" + text + "'\n\thas citation(s): " + citation);
    }
}
```

For your provided input this collects the following:

```
The text: 'The sociological assumption is a constraint on the trust in the underlying social graph: the graph needs to have strong trust as evidenced, for example, by face to face interaction demonstrating social nodes knowledge of each other '
    has citation(s): 10, 11
The text: '. While the first assumption has been questioned recently in '
    has citation(s): 8
```

After reading your comments, it seems that you want to find the citations that may appear in any given sentence. Since sentences are finished with fullstops, and may contain more than one citation, you need to approach that in a two stage process:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "...";

    List<CitedSentence> citations = new ArrayList<CitedSentence>();
    for (String sentence : convertToSentences(input)) {
        citations.addAll(findCitations(sentence));
    }

    for (CitedSentence citation : citations) {
        System.out.println(citation);
    }
}

public static String[] convertToSentences(String input) {
    return input.split("\\s*\\.\\s*");
}

private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
public static List<CitedSentence> findCitations(String sentence) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
    List<CitedSentence> result = new ArrayList<CitedSentence>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String citation = matcher.group(1);

        for (String currentCitation : citation.split(",")) {
            result.add(new CitedSentence(sentence, currentCitation.trim()));
        }
    }

    return result;
}

static class CitedSentence {
    String sentence, citation;

    public CitedSentence(String sentence, String citation) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
        this.citation = citation;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[" + citation + "]: " + sentence;
    }
}
```

When I run this, it produces the following:

```
[10]: The sociological assumption is a constraint on the trust in the underlying social graph: the graph needs to have strong trust as evidenced, for example, by face to face interaction demonstrating social nodes knowledge of each other [10, 11]
[11]: The sociological assumption is a constraint on the trust in the underlying social graph: the graph needs to have strong trust as evidenced, for example, by face to face interaction demonstrating social nodes knowledge of each other [10, 11]
[8]: While the first assumption has been questioned recently in [8], where it is shown that even the Copyright is held by the author/owner(s)
```

I only used part of the sample text.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 (^.|[.?!])+([^?!.]{0,})\[[0-9, ]{0,}?\]
```